# How to sort a file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I am beginner to python and trying to write a script to sort a file based on the integer which is somewhere in the middle of the line. The input text looks similar to (the words in every line are not same but the format is the same)

```
abc_def/: "ghi/jkl/mno/", 2: pqrs: tuv
abc_lmno/: "ghi/jkl/mno/", 5: pqrs: tuv
abc_def/: "ghi/jkl/mno/", 1: pqrs: tuv
```

(The text might look lame but I am trying to learn all the possible ways to sort).

I tried the following the code:

```
output.writelines(sorted(input, key = lambda line: int(line.split()[2])))
```

giving an error saying "Index out of range"

I tried considering the first word after the second space in a line to sort the line. But it did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why for example not print what `line.split()` looks like on every line of input? and check if there's one with length less than 3?
maybe there's any empty line in the end?

Comment: `sorted(lines, key=lambda l: int(l.split()[2][:-1]))` works for me. Your line is not what you expect I would wager. Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: This isn't really about sorting - this is about effective parsing of a tabular file in a custom format. I would suggest looking into regex for a more general solution. Alternatively - think how this file was created, if this format has a name, and it might have an existing parser for python